# c# and MySql - Will the server be down running multiple (thousands) queries?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-connector

I have more than

- 300K products,
- 400K product variants,
- 1M prices

My goal is build a strongly-typed model like

```
public class Product
{
    //all properties here
    public IList<ProductVariant> ProductVariants { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVariant
{
    //all properties here
    public IList<ProductVariantPrice> ProductVariantPrices { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVariantPrice
{
    //all properties here
}
```

to get an

```
IList<Product> Products
```

I read a lot about using one bigger query or many smallest queries and answers are for smallest queries.

In my case I have to  run

- 1 query to get all product
- foreach product 1 query to get all variants: 300k queries
- foreach variant 1 query to get all prices: 400k queries

Total queries are 700k queries.
Is acceptable 700k queries to get my complex model? Or the risk is the server go down?

What's the best practice to do that?

Thanks

Comment: You need to reevaluate on why you have to make these many queries? Can you avoid it? Can you use pagination or. caching? Can you use some other type of database such as DynamoDb ?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I have to migrate from mysql to mongo. MySql is the source of normalized data and I need MongoDb to statistics. So I have to migrate all data from mysql to mongo

Comment: so this is a one-off exercise? In that case, if downtime is required then it might just have to be a temporary outage, I guess. Or maybe you could restore a backup to another server and run the migration off that, so it doesn't affect other production databases on the main server

Comment: If your database server has enough processing power and memory and database it only used for migration activity then it won't have any issues. It will take time though to complete the migration. Just make sure that you don't query large amount of data in one single query.

Comment: @ADyson Data can change in MySql so I need to scheduled my migration (every week for example) to migrate to mongodb. So I can't allow that the server goes down

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya My MySql DB is not used only for migration. It is the source from that data are shown on the front-end. My query select small data but with many records. Do I have to use one single connection?

Comment: You need to automate this to back up the database, restore on a different server and perform migration there and then delete the restored database after migration. I would not suggest to do this on live production database.

Comment: Whether to use single connection or not that depends on how are you planning to do this. I suggest to check if this can be done via some existing tools instead of writing this stuff from scratch.

Comment: @MiniDev1 I see. I think I was confused by your terminology. "Migration" normally means a one-off move from one platform to another, where you switch off the old platform afterwards. I think what you're doing here is "extracting" or "exporting" data. But, as Chetan also says, you could still consider doing this task on a regular basis on a separate dedicated server.

Comment: The correct terminology is synchronization data. Anyway first time I synchronize all data and then for difference (only data that has changed)

Comment: If this is actually a question about synchronization, you may want to ask an actual question about synchronization. While I generally would expect that reading 1M prices at once (maybe 50-ish MB?) won't put any stress on your server, while 700k queries will probably do, in a synchronization task you have even more options that you might get to know about then (e.g. mark and only request modified rows, stretch doing 700k queries over 24 hours (8 queries/s), extract modifications from the binlog, run any update on both servers when they occur, ...)

Comment: In my book, it is a 'red flag' when I hear of a single query returning 400K rows.  Sure, the database can do it, but it will choke the client, especially if it tries to display all those rows on a User Interface.  Even 'paginating' that many rows is a no-no in my book.